# Auto-close for streams in IOUtils methods

Tags: java, stream, apache-commons, apache-commons-io

Apache [commons-io](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-io/commons-io) library is almost a de-facto way for IO operations in java. What really bothers me is that it does not provide methods for automatically stream closing after io operations.

Desired workflow:

```
IOUtils.write(myBytes, new FileOutputStream("/path/to/file.txt"));
```

Current workflow:

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("/path/to/file.txt")
IOUtils.write(myBytes, fos);
fos.close();
```

Can I do it in one line? What alternatives do I have? If nothing is available, why?

Comment: `java.nio.file.Files` makes a lot of this obsolete... `Files.write(Paths.get(...), myBytes)`.

Comment: @JonSkeet wow, that's nice, I see that writeLines method was introduced in 1.8 so the functionality is almost the same. don't you mind to write an answer?

Comment: Well, it didn't seem to really answer the question you asked, so much as make that question redundant :)

Comment: @JonSkeet well, at least I got my one-liner, tx )

Answer (score 0):

There are several reasons:

- Some other workflows still have references to that stream and may want to write to it in the near future. There is no way for `IOUtils` to know this information. Closing a stream in such a way might create undesired behaviour very quickly.
- IO operations should be atomic. `write()` writes to stream and `close()` closes it. There is **no reason** to do both things at the same time, especially if the methods's name explicitly says `write()`, not`writeAndClose()`.

Write your own `writeAndClose()` function.

```
public static void writeAndClose(String path, Byte[] bytes)
{
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(path)
    IOUtils.write(bytes, fos);
    fos.close();
}
```

Comment: I fully understand the reasons, my question was if there are other methods for this, and if there aren't any - why. Jon Skeet gave a good core java solution

Comment: The statements "I fully understand the reasons" and "if there aren't any - why" are contradictory.

Comment: what was the reason not to introduce method writeAndClose in IOUtils?

Comment: Questions of the type "why not introduce method X in package Y" make no sense because none of us are part of the package's dev team. For sake of completeness, the answer to your question is bullet point 2 in my answer.